# Firebase error: (app/invalid-app-argument) in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

When I run this code (react native), the following error appears:

> FirebaseError: Firebase: firebase.database() takes either no argument or a Firebase App instance. (app/invalid-app-argument).

Here's the code (when I run the similar code in other files(inside the same project) works perfectly):

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import * as firebase from "firebase";

class screen extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        firebase
          .database()
          .ref("users/" + user.uid + "/keys")
          .on("value", function (snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot.val()); //works
            snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
              console.log("hello"); //works
              var key = childSnapshot.val();
              firebase
                .database("users/" + key + "/whatever")
                .on("value", function (snapshot) {
                  console.log(snapshot.val()); //Doesn't work
                });
            });
          });
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
       <Text>Hello</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default screen;
```

Comment: Are you sure that the error message refers to this code?  If so, how did you make that connection?

Comment: It seems likely that you didn't properly initialize Firebase. Assuming react-native-firebase, then you need to set up your config as explained [here](https://rnfirebase.io/#configure-firebase-with-android-credentials) and should be importing `@react-native-firebase/database` rather than the raw Firebase SDK. If you are not using a third party lib, then the code you shared here can't produce the error described.

Comment: This is react native and this is not how you use firebase with react-native. follow the guide

Answer (score 1):

Ok i figured it out. I had to write the reference of the database inside "ref()" not inside "database()"... silly error haha